# Zend Framework Input/Output XSS Filtering: Strip Tags, Textile, BBCode

Tags: xss, bbcode, htmlpurifier, textile, zend-filter-strip-tags

In my CMS application, administration users can add HTML content via a WYSIWYG editor that gets filtered by [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).  I am now wanting to add a message board functionality. I am planning on using the [Zend StripTags Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html#zend.filter.set.striptags) without a whitelist to remove all HTML, and then provide for rich markup by using Zend's [BBCode](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.markup.parsers.html#zend.markup.parsers.bbcode) or [Textile](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.markup.parsers.html#zend.markup.parsers.textile) parsers.

These are my questions:

1. Can XSS make it through `StripTags` if I have no whitelist?
2. Does adding BBCode or Textile as an output parser reintroduce the possibility of XSS?

Comment: Can you give an example on how you implemented MarkDown in the Zend Framework? Where did you place the view helper for example?

Comment: @UnderDog - I didn't end up using a view helper. I have updated my answer to include some implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [a post about Markdown here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690601/markdown-and-xss), and [another article linked in an answer to that post](http://michelf.com/weblog/2010/markdown-and-xss/), it appears that reintroducing XSS into a document is not only possible, but trivial.  To be secure, I will need to run content through [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) as the **final** step in the **output** filter chain. Because I am concerned with the performance of [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) as an output filter, I am looking into using [Wibble](https://github.com/padraic/wibble) instead.

This still leaves the first question unanswered, but in my case, that step will be unnecessary.

---

I discovered when trying to use them, that Zend's BBCode and Textile are horribly buggy.  I instead used [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/).  Also, [Wibble](https://github.com/padraic/wibble) doesn't seem like it's production ready yet.

I used two columns in my database: `content` and `html`. The `content` column holds the user-submitted text. When saving the record, I convert `content` to HTML with [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/), pass it through [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) and then save that value to the `html` column. I am not converting will every view that way.

---

**Implementation Details**

I put [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) here: `library/markdown.php`.  In my active record model, using `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract`, I use the `_insert()` and `_update()` hooks to process the values before the record is saved:

```
// prepare html based on the content
require_once 'markdown.php';
$flt = new My_Filter_HtmlPurifier();
$this->html = $flt->filter(Markdown($this->content));
```

Here is my [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) filter:

```
/**
 * Based on examples from http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/365-Example-Zend-Framework-Blog-Application-Tutorial-Part-8-Creating-and-Editing-Blog-Entries-with-a-dash-of-HTMLPurifier.html
 */
require_once 'HTMLPurifier.includes.php';
require_once 'HTMLPurifier.autoload.php';

class My_Filter_HtmlPurifier implements Zend_Filter_Interface
{
    /** @var HTMLPurifier */
    protected $_htmlPurifier;

    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        // set up configuration
        $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
        $config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'My HTML Purifier Filter');
        $config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 3); // increment when configuration changes
//        $config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null); // comment out after finalizing the config

        // Doctype
        $config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');

        // Add support for object (flash) tags
        $config->set('HTML.SafeObject', true);
        $config->set('Output.FlashCompat', true); // IE Support

        // Custom Filters
        // Add support for iframes - YouTube, Vimeo...
        $config->set('Filter.Custom', array(new HTMLPurifier_Filter_MyIframe()));

        // Add support for anchor targets
        $config->set('Attr.AllowedFrameTargets', array('_blank', '_self', '_target', '_top'));

        // configure caching
        $cachePath = CUST_APP_PATH . '/../cache/htmlpurifier';
        if (!is_dir($cachePath)) {
            mkdir($cachePath, 0700, true);
        }
        $cachePath = realpath($cachePath);
        $config->set('Cache.SerializerPath', $cachePath);

        // allow for passed-in options
        if (!is_null($options)) {
            //$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                $config->set($option[0], $option[1], $option[2]);
            }
        }

        // create the local instance
        $this->_htmlPurifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    }

    public function filter($value)
    {
        return $this->_htmlPurifier->purify($value);
    }
}
```